# Laravel 8 pagination Error - Column 'is_deleted' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and have stumbled upon a problem. Would you mind advising the right way of doing it if I am doing it incorrectly? For example, I have 3 tables: `product`, `product_category`, `product_image`, as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `short_description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `specification` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `product_image` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**Question 1**

I am paginating my data on the frontend, but I am getting the following error with the below code.

> Column 'is_deleted' in where clause is ambiguous.

```
$objData = DB::table('product')->join('product_category', 'product_category.id',
    'product.product_category_id')
    ->where($arrWhere)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        global $request;

        // If search sent
        if ($request->query('search')) {
            $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $request->query('search') . '%')
                ->orWhere('short_description', 'like', '%' . $request->query('search') . '%')
                ->orWhere('specification', 'like', '%' . $request->query('search') . '%')
                ->orWhere('size', 'like', '%' . $request->query('search') . '%');
        }
    })->orderBy($request->query('sortBy'), $strSortType)->select('product.*, product_category.*, 
        product.is_deleted as product_is_deleted, product_category.is_deleted as product_category_is_deleted')
    ->paginate($request->query('rowsPerPage'));
```

**Question 2**

I have a `product_image` table, and I want to attach the product images with each product as an array of `$product->images`. Currently, I am doing the below, it is working, but I am not sure it's the right way. Can someone please advise a cleaner Laravel way of doing this?

```
// Get product_ids
$arrProductId = array();
foreach ($objData as $objProduct) {
    $arrProductId[] = $objProduct->id;
}

// Get product images
$arrProductImage = ProductImage::whereIn('product_id', $arrProductId)->get();

// Bind the product images to the rows to return
$arrRows = array();
foreach ($objData->items() as $objProduct) {

    $objProduct->images = array();

    foreach ($arrProductImage as $objProductImage) {
        if ($objProductImage->product_id == $objProduct->id) {
            $objProduct->images[] = $objProductImage->image;
        }
    }
    $arrRows[] = $objProduct;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

Remake your migration and put

```
$table->boolean('is_deleted')->default(0);
```

Second of all, try and rething your relationship between tables. You can accomplish the same thing with Eloquent.

```
Class Product
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class)->select(['column1', 'column2']);
    }
}

Class Category
{
    public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Query example:

```
$products = Product::with('category')->where('some_field', $filter['field']);

if ($filter['someOtherField']) {
   $products->where('some_other_field', $filter['someOtherField']);
}

$products->paginate(15);
```

in blade do

```
{{$products->links}}
```

to show the default pagination.

Comment: First do this and then you will need to rethink on how to add images to products. You'll see it's more easier.

I understand you are a beginner in Laravel, this is why I recommend you to first take a look at "Laravel Eloquent Relations" - search on youtube, you'll find many tutorials very good explained.

If you understand the basics of it, you'll start to slowly fall in love with the way things are done in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, i solved my problem using your answer..
 
like this 

 $objData = Product::with('product_category')->with('product_image')

Can you also pls advise how can i limit the number of parameters returned like if i want to get only product category name and id columns only how can i modify above for it.

Comment: To only get some of the columns 

you can 

Product::select('column','otherColumn')->with('category') etc.

Comment: But how do i get it for the "with" tables for example i only want some columns from the category table and full columns for the product table..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @amateur_coder - I have edited the answer above. Look at category relation on product and keep in mind that column1  and column2 should be from relation: in your case, columns from category.